# Swagger not working from azure API management service

Tags: azure

Steps to enable swagger. From code it is enabled. From API App it is working. But not when I place my API app behind API management

Comment: swagger is just the "specs". Is the API working when it's behind API Management?

Comment: yes API is working... ebenm i could load the swagger.json file... but not the swagger UI  @Thiago Custodio